# Removal of bad hyperlinks and the content inside of them

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Ok, basically I have an array of bad urls and I would like to search through a string and strip them out. I want to strip everything from the opening tag to the closing tag, but only if the url in the hyperlink is in the array of bad urls. Here is how I would picture it working but I don't understand regular expressions well.

```
foreach($bad_urls as $bad_url){
    $pattern = "/<a*$bad_url*</a>/";
    $replacement = ' ';
    preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to remove "a" tag completely ?

Comment: Yes; I want to find every $bad_url's "a" tag and completely remove the tag and the text inside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [do not try to parse HTML using regular expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Just [load up the HTML in a DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), find all the `<a>` tags and check the `href` property. Much simpler and fool-proof.

Comment: Glad you steered me away from regular expressions. I got a little bit lost on the DOMDocument. I ended up just using a bunch of strpos/strrpos and substrings/concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your 'bad urls' are properly formatted URLs, I would suggest doing something like this:

```
foreach($bad_urls as $bad_url){
    $pattern = '/<[aA]\s.+[href|HREF]\=\"' . convert_to_pattern($bad_url) . '\".+<\/[aA]>/msU';
    $replacement = ' ';
    $content = preg_replace_all($pattern, $replacement, $content);
}
```

and separately

```
function convert_to_pattern($url)
{
    searches = array('%', '&', '?', '.', '/', ';', ' ');
    replaces = array('\%','\&','\?','\.','\/','\;','\ ');
    return preg_replace_all($searches, $replaces, $url);
}
```